# How come my bot won't realise the parameters?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have a bot which is supposed to give info on a player when in the command. The command is:

```
-Whois [USER]
```

and then the bot replies with the information.

I entered 'iamonf1r3' as the user parameter and it came up with the response for mip232. Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def Whois(parameter):
    name = parameter
    if name == "mip232" or name == "Mip" or "219884374378676224":
        await client.say("Roblox Name: `mip232` \nDiscord Name: `Mip#3981` \nPin: `FS01` \nRank: `Chief Fire Officer` \nDivision: `All` \nActivity Level: `Active` \nDriving Level: `Advanced` \nDisciplinary Action: `None`")
    elif name == "iamonf1r3" or "iamonf1r3" or "335014153460776962":
        await client.say("Roblox Name: `iamonf1r3` \nDiscord Name: `iamonf1r3#7277` \nPin: `FS02` \nRank: `Deputy Chief Fire Officer` \nDivision: `All` \nActivity Level: `Active` \nDriving Level: `Advanced` \nDisciplinary Action: `None`")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are using or in the wrong way**

To be honest you completly messed your "or states" up

Every or has to have a new condition
Right:

```py
if name == "mip232" or name == "Mip" or "219884374378676224":
```

Wrong

```py
if name == "mip232" or name == "Mip" or name == "219884374378676224":
```

You did the same with your elif but I'll leave it to you to fix this statement.

**Explanation:**
`if <CONDITION> or <CONFITION>`

The parameter "name" you gave in the first condition is not given to the second or.

Additionally if you ask `if name` it will just see if this variable is present => True if present, False if None.

So your last `or "219884374378676224"` basically returns a True for the if since "219884374378676224" is present because you just initialised it in the same block and it is not a query.

**Try reading this: https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/**